# Creating Umbrella framework in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks

How to add two or more than two framework in a single framework. Is there any way to add more than two framework in a single binary so that If I have to add it in "Embedded Binaries" then I will add only single framework not multiple framework. My only use case is that, I have used 7 frameworks in my project and right now I have to add all the 7 frameworks separately, but I didn't want to add 7 frameworks everytime. I just want to make an umbrella framework that will include all these 7 frameworks and I will add only single umbrella framework inside "Embedded Binaries".